# Is it possible to run Cypress tests from a different repository?

Tags: cypress, github-actions

I have Cypress tests in a dedicated repo. The front-end code is in a different repo. When a developer opens a Pull Request I want them to have the option to trigger a subset of tests. Is this possible? As I'm unable to find any examples of this.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions:

### Checkout the e2e tests repository from the front-end repository pipelines

You can just use

```
  - name: Check out my e2e tests
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      repository: orgname/reponame
      path: ./my-e2e-tests
```

This will clone the e2e tests repository to a new `my-e2e-tests` directory, and then you can checkout your current (front-end) code and perform the rest of your steps.

See: https://github.com/actions/checkout#checkout-multiple-repos-side-by-side

### Use reusable workflows

You can create a [reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows) and you perform the necessary setups for your e2e tests, and then call the new reusable workflow from your front-end repository as a job as for example:

```
jobs:
  run-e2e-tests:
    uses: my-org/example-repo/.github/workflows/reusable-e2e-workflow.yml@main
    with:
      base-url: http://baseurl.org
    secrets:
      token: ${{ secrets.envPAT }}
```

This job as you know, will run in parallel with your other jobs, so you may want to use a [`needs`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-jobs-in-a-workflow#example-requiring-successful-dependent-jobs) argument to make your deployment job wait for this e2e tests job for example.

### Use composite-actions

You can create a [composite action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action) that does a set of preparations for your e2e tests, one of them would be pulling the e2e tests from their repository using the `actions/checkout` action. This will abstract all the needed steps to prepare for your e2e tests as you will only call a shared action in your PR pipeline.

---

Other links that may help:

- https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action#start-server: If you want to use cypress's shared Github action
- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action: If you want to create a base docker image containing all cypress/proxy setups

---

About your statement:

> I want them to have the option to trigger a subset of tests.

If you mean that you want to allow them to run workflows manually:

Have a look at the [`workflow_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) trigger, there you can choose to run a workflow against any branch you want, you will have a selector on the workflow run pop-up.